# ethers can't get pure function return value

Tags: reactjs, blockchain, solidity, web3js, ethers.js

I built a test solidity pure function to display a greeting message.

It only returns a string "Hello User".

Here is the contract code:

```
 //SPDX-License-Identifier: Unlicense

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
contract Greeter {
    function SayHi() public pure returns(string memory){
        return "Hello User";
    }
}
```

and here is the function in react. I'm calling the solidity function. (Note: all required connection to wallet and to contract is done)

```
  const getMsg = async () => {
    try {
      if (!ethereum) return alert("Please install MetaMask.");

      console.log('Fetching MEssage...')
      let msg = await Contract.SayHi();
      console.log('Message:', msg)
      // setmessage(msg);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);

      throw new Error("No ethereum object");
    }
  };
```

after this I get nothing in the log statement. I didn't get the return value.

So how can I access it?

Comment: Is the JS snippet connected to the same network where the contract is deployed?

Comment: @PetrHejda what is that mean ? how can i check that

Answer (score 0):

**Issue is Solved by deploying the contract on the same Network that i am connected to by:**

```
 npx hardhat run --network ropsten  .\scripts\deploy.js
```